# Approximating a length metric from below with Finsler metrics

Tags: mg.metric-geometry

I have a question about the first result in the [paper](http://m.mathnet.ru/links/48cdb1d6a1e6777814a8a8b543098968/aa102.pdf) "two
counterexamples in low-dimensional length geometry", by Burago, Ivanov and Shoenthal.

First there is an **open question**: In the two-dimensional disk, can any length
metric can be approximated by Finsler metrics *from below*? Here a length metric is one which is equal to the infimum of curve lengths; it need not be a Riemannian or even a Finsler metric.

The above paper shows that in dimension 3 there is a
counterexample $(D^3\subset \mathbb{E}^3,d)$. The idea of the construction is as follows: There is a
non-trivial shortest geodesic from $a$ to $b$ with $a_i\rightarrow
a,\ b_i \rightarrow b$ s.t. $d(a_i,b_i)\rightarrow 0$.

Here I think that $d(a,b)$ may be 0, in which case $d$ is not a metric. I do not understand lemma 2.3, which claims to prove that $d$ is a metric. **What am I missing?**

Thank you for your attention.

**More detail** (Not question. It is for better understanding on their proof) :

In $\mathbb{E}^3$ we perturb a tubular neighborhood
$U_i$ of the segment $a_ib_i$ wrt the Euclidean metric $d_E$. In $U_i$,
consider linked simple closed curves $\{ S_k\}_{k=1}^{n_i}$ where $a_i\in S_1,\ b_i\in
S_{n_i},\ S_k$ is a simple closed curve and they are linked  (Note that this can not happen in dimension 2.)

That is, around $S_k$ we give a metric $\frac{1}{in_i} d_E$, as elaborated in the paper.

To show that $d(a_i,b_i)$ is very small, they use the fact :

> (Linked Circles) In $(\mathbb{E}^3,d_E)$, if two linked simple closed curves lie at distance at least $1$ from each other then length of each curve is at least $2\pi $

Finally, it seems to me that they used the fact:

> If a length space $X_n$ has a Gromov-Hausdorff limit $X$ which is complete, then $X$ is a length space.

Comment: The statement in your first grey box looks to me like nonsense (why can't $c_1$ and $c_2$ be arbitrarily small?), but I don't see this used in the paper. They use some lemmas that relate the distance and length of LINKED curves in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

The second grey box (limit of length spaces is a length space) is a standard fact. For example it is Theorem 7.5.1 in the Burago-Burago-Ivanov book "A Course in Metric Geometry".

For the first part of your question, I think you may have gotten confused between the metric $d$ (which is a metric) and the supposed Finsler metric $\rho$.

Comment: @ Matt F. : Thank you for elaborate editting.

Comment: @ user103319 : Thank you for your comment. I edited for clarifying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Construct a length metric space as follows : Around given shortest path between two points, construct linked circles s.t. each circle has small length.

If the length metric is Finsler, then two points around circles has a small distance.